# How Can I Keep an Economy Stable Using Food as Currency?

Tags: economy, food, currency, class-structure

I am creating a world where the currency (the only currency) is tablets that dissolve in water to create food. Each tablet provides all of the nutritional needs for an average adult for one day. The gruel doesn't taste particularly good, and the person feels hungry again right away. But, most people rarely eat anything else and the population stays fairly healthy (barring plagues, natural disasters and the occasional war).

In most ways, my people have reached a technological level about that of Europe in 1650.

The small planet has five island continents (think Australia), with urban centers mostly in the coastal areas. Ocean water is potable, so there is plenty of water for everybody. Unfortunately, there are no aquatic animals.

On four of the five continents, most of the land is also very barren. The largely barren continents have pockets of fertile soil, in which various crops can be grown. Every continent also has indigenous large herbivores that eat the few plants that grow wild on that continent, plants that can't be digested by my people.

The fifth continent is nearly overgrown with a fast growing plant that is processed to make the tablets. The plants cannot be made to grow anyplace else but on that continent. (There is magic involved here, the nature of which will be revealed towards the end of the story.)

The total population on the planet is about 100 million people, with the population pretty evenly split among four of the five continents. Each continent has a monarch and nobility. The monarch and nobles own all of the land and everything it produces including the wild animals (meat). Poaching or stealing of food other than the tablets is punishable by death on all five continents. Three of the continents deal in slaves and on the continent that makes the tablets, almost all of the (grueling) work is done by slaves. The two other continents on which slavery is legal get a lot of tablets in exchange for slaves. Slaves on my planet are slaves for life, as are their progeny (even if the other parent is a free person).

Food other than the tablets is scarce. Peasants are lucky to eat real food a few times a week, slaves never do. On the other hand, few nobles have ever tasted tablet gruel.

The monarch and most of the nobles on the continent that produces food are extremely rich, extremely powerful, and solidly evil. They like things as they are and want to keep them that way. The fifth continent has its royal family, perhaps 300 rich and powerful nobles, a few thousand pretty darn comfortable peasants, and 50,000 slaves.

My story begins at least 150 years later, at the cusp of an industrial revolution. I want the economy of my little planet to have been fairly stable for the past 150 years.

It is here that I ask the question:

**How can I keep this economy stable for at least 150 years (200 to 250 years is better)?**

I figure that the tablets have to be produced at a rate of at least 100 million per day (every day), but the average day will produce enough so that basic necessities can be purchased with small caches of tablets. As a rule, tablets are not hoarded even by the rich. Wealth is accumulated in the form of 'stuff'. Additionally, my people have the sense (or perhaps I can address the issue later as a matter of biology) to keep the population stable.

This currency is mostly consumed as quickly as it is "minted".

I am not averse to using magic to make things *work*, but I'd like to keep it pretty subtle. Magic is not a day to day concern of people not involved in the manufacture of food tablets.  The world has a significant maritime structure that has evolved because of the tablets. It's a small planet, the sailing distance between continents is only a few days. So, 'spreading the wealth' is a non-magical industry important to my people.

OH! And as far as my people suspect, they are the only 'intelligent' people in the universe.

(Yes, this question was inspired by The Force Awakens.)

Comment: How does the fourth continent that has people but no slaves get tablets?  Why does the tablet continent need new slaves continuously (otherwise it would seem to have a growing population)?

Comment: @Brythan The slaves on the "evil" continent have a very short lifespan, they are literally worked to death. The 'pockets of fertile soil' on the non-slave continents produce crops that are saleable. Think silk.

Comment: Although slavery is illegal on two continents, a lot of nobles on all five continents own them, particularly house and sex slaves.

Comment: I think the rich people benefit from the people eating it because they have to get it somewhere, otherwise it would be gone some day and thus they need employment from the food producers

Comment: Mass manufacturing and distribution of 100 million food pills *per day*, cross-continental communications, and unified laws and technology... how is this supported by 1650s technology?

Comment: @Schwern The manufacturing of the pills involves a bit of magic. The pills themselves and the plants they come from are also magic. The world has a significant maritime structure that has evolved because of the pills. It's a small planet, the sailing distance between continents is only a few days.

Comment: How much food can they harvest from the sea or the other lands? Because right now it looks like you produce almost EXACTLY as much food as you need to consume (100 million pills/day for 100 million people), so how can anyone accumulate wealth?

Comment: @JasonK The speed of manufacture is a key question in the story. Wealth is not accumulated in tablets, but in 'stuff'. Since the manufacturing of tablets is magic, my limits are of my making. A shortage of tablets causes peasants and slaves to starve - a very key plot point. At this point I'm considering 100 million a bare minimum per day, but that isn't average. My necessary average production will probably be a topic for another question. My peasants need to buy shoes and soap. Food (other than the tablets) is scarce and expensive.

Comment: @Jolenealaska you may want to read some of Philip Jose Farmer's RIVERWORLD. It had an economy somewhat similar to this, where every day each person was granted a daily ration of food. Similar feudal type societies with slaves held just for their food rations developed there as well.

Comment: @Jolenealaska - You say, "*My peasants need to buy shoes and soap.*" What do your peasants **sell** in order to acquire the money to buy shoes and soap? Their own children as slaves?

Comment: @LuísHenrique some of them are cobblers, others of them are smiths. A few slaves read, they make good teachers. My people are very much like people in 17th century England, except that selling children as slaves is kind of socially acceptable and is often done, especially if the child is of the "wrong" sex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer depends on a lot of small details which one might fit into a storyline.  From [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-characteristics-of-a-good-currency-and-how-does-Bitcoin-compare-to-that) by a former financial adviser:

> 1. Generally Accepted - Many people must accept the money as a settlement of debt or as a discharge of obligation.
> 2. Durable - Its quality/value does not deteriorate over time, which is why we do not tend to use food products as money. (*my note: your food does not seem to deteriorate, so I don't think it has a problem with this criteria*)
> 3. Divisible - If you divide the money in half, each half should be worth 50% of the whole. This is why we tend not to use diamonds or artwork as money.
> 4. Stable/Consistent - The value does not fluctuate substantially with time.
> 5. Transportable - It is easy to move from one place to another.
> 6. Scarce - It is difficult to acquire.
> 7. Easily recognizable - It needs to be obvious what it is, mostly for the purposes of #1.
> 8. Difficult to Counterfeit - This mostly has to do with #6.

You can analyze your food tablets to see how well they fare, and possibly shape them slightly to better fit that list of requirements.

One detail which I think would be very important is looking at how transactions with large numbers of tablets would work.  Let's say I work for the nobles, and I have a million dollar helicopter that I want to trade for a piece of rare artwork (okay, maybe those aren't *exactly* 1650's items, but you get the idea).  Will I accept, say, 300,000 tablets in exchange for the helicopter and will another party accept 300,000 tablets in exchange for their artwork?  This is the "Generally Accepted" criteria listed above.  In a more difficult case, I sell my helicopter for 300,000 tablets, but my art vendor has sold the artwork before I could get my hands on it.  I now have 300,000 tablets on my hands, enough food for me to eat for 822 years straight!  Am I still happy with my trade?  Am I comfortable that I can still find ways to get the desired value out of 822 man-years worth of food?

If you can convince the readers that the answer is "yes," you are certainly on your way to using food as a currency.

Scarcity would be a big deal for this currency.  If the nobles start manipulating the food supply, and the poor are dependent on it, it may artificially raise the value of the tablets above their "actual value."  This is no problem, as long as the tablets remain scarce.  However, if the market is suddenly flooded with tablets when the nobles stop making it artificially scarce, the value of the tablets will plummet.  This would actually create a complicated metastability that you would have to deal with: the value of the stockpiles of tablets the nobles have would be worth more as long as the poor are oppressed and hungry.

Comment: Keep in mind that there can easily be several currencies that are used at the same time, often for different purposes (like gold/silver/bronze of old). A labourer might receive two tablets for a day's work, but a noble might pay in gold (or pearls, exotic feathers or whatever) for the equivalent of a helicopter which would be 300,000 tablets otherwise. Most of the trading will probably be done in tablets but especially large transactions call for something else.

Comment: @PeterS. The OP did state that these tablets are his only currency.  I do agree that there would probably be dome other means of transporting several hundred thousand tablets worth of value, but for the OP's question, the value would at least need to be measured in tablets, so the value of payment (gold, pearls, etc.) would need to be primarially represented as the payment's proxy for its value in tablets.

Comment: You have a point there, @CortAmmon!

Comment: To add to the answer... manipulating the money supply would be probably frowned upon, since it could lead to slave uprisings on the one hand and financial losses for powerful nobles on the other hand - not exactly people a prospective stock market manipulator would want to anger. So you could see nobles burning excess tablets or gracefully allowing a useful slave to have a child after all, if they feel generous.

Comment: @PeterS. Slave uprisings and manipulating the money supply?? *Stop reading ahead!*

Comment: @CortAmmon That is how I am doing it. A large purchase may be worth 300,000 tablets, but the actual tablets may not change hands.

Comment: @Jolenealaska they don't change hands? What does?  A note that says something like "i agree to give the bearer 300,000 tablets" ? If the tablets don't change hands then the helicopter is worth 1 art, not 300,000 tablets, and the art is worth 1 helicopter... Unless you have a contract system where everything needs to be expressed in tablet value, which sounds like how we do it (we just started with gold). You need some caveat where things absolutely have to be valued in tablets, otherwise its hard to believe that these folks didn't figure out currency on their way to the industrial revolution

Comment: @JeffMeden Lets say a noble on continent four wants to buy a ship from continent three. The ship is worth 100,000 tablets. The noble on continent four has silk, gold, feathers and art worth 100,000 tablets. The ship seller on continent three agrees to the transaction. For day-to-day things, only tablets are used. For large transactions, my people can get a little creative. But, every transaction is worked out as a value in tablets. Just like an American will think of everything in terms of dollars.

Comment: @Jolenealaska reminds me a lot of the movie In Time, the currency is something that has to be used, making it a great way to oppress people but a terrible way to run a stable society. Books like Extraordinary Popular Delusions and The Madness of Crowds and Devil Take the Hindmost highlight how fragile basic currency systems are, the idea of stability for even 15 years is fantastic, 150 years requires some sort of intense plot point.

Comment: @JeffMeden I'd love to see that fleshed out into an answer.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [Kokudaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokudaka) of feudal Japan for a historical example. A landowner's wealth was determined by the amount of *koku* the land could purportedly produce. A *koku* was equivalent to the amount of rice needed to feed a man for a year (about 5 bushels). A smaller unit, the *masu* defined the amount for a day, similar to your tablets. Daimyo's estates had anywhere from 10,000 *koku* to over a million. This is not to say that their wealth was exclusively in rice. Think about how we talk about rich estates as being worth "billions of dollars" as if they could liquidate all of their assets whenever they pleased. A noble's wealth might be defined by the amount of tablets their estate could earn, but in practice the actual food would go towards feeding their subjects while the majority of their wealth would be in goods.
The feudal Japanese system also included the [*ryō*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ry%C5%8D), a currency unit equivalent to four *koku* (later changed to 1:1). The *ryō* and its lesser denominations were used for everyday spending. So in this way, food was the basis of the currency, but people weren't literally taking bushels of rice to the market.

Comment: My people will literally take tablets to the market to buy soap, or a frying pan. I will look further into the Kokudaka, I might find information there useful to me. Thanks. +1

Comment: In your case, the tablets are small enough to replace low denomination coins, but imagine if I want to buy a house for 100,000 tablets. Am I literally counting out 100,000 tablets, or can I use some currency that represents that value?

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your premise.

Money is something that has to circulate. If a society has a monetary economy, the circulation of commodities is intimately tied to the circulation of money; if circulation of money stops, the circulation of commodities also stops - and if it is a monetary economy, circulation of commodities must be the main, if not the only, way commodities are distributed.

Problem is, if money has other utilities besides being a means of payment, people will always be tempted to use money as something else. In our case, people will be tempted to **eat** their money. And the only thing keeping them from that is the idea that the food that they might buy with their money is more (or much better) food than the money itself. But your description goes on to say that proper food is usually unavailable, so people eat money instead of it. Which means your money doesn't circulate properly; it is eaten, and therefore is withdrawn from circulation.

In a low fantasy world, this would be extremely unstable; it would make the production of any other food inviable (who would pay for proper food? How do you prevent people involved in the production of other edible items from eating them, instead of selling it for... bad food?). All of this means that the economy will always be on the verge of returning to a "natural" (ie, non-monetary) economy, or, even more, that it will be basically a natural economy, with only a few markets where money actually circulates (and this would mean an economy that in all likeness is immature for an industrial revolution - there would be not enough demand for non-agricultural products to sustain an industrial sector, for people would have eaten their money before buying industrial gadgets).

Of course, since your world is high fantasy, these things can always be explained away by magic; and if you start from the premise that the workings of your world are magic, it is probably better not to try and make all things explainable in terms of a non-magical world. You have to suspend your readers disbelief; if you try to explain too much, you risk raising their doubts instead of dispelling them. The money in your world is tablets of food. As long as you explain how they would be able to buy both a large house and a pair of shoes, that's it; if you try to explain how they would run a stock market, or even banks, based on food-money, you risk to put all your system under scrutiny, instead of keeping your readers focused in your story, which is what really matters.